# Loose coupling and starting activities

Tags: android, android-activity, loose-coupling

I want to keep my app as loosely coupled as possible, and most of is done with IoC

however, at some point, i need to launch different activities,and the class implementing this activity, could be any,meaning i don't want to define a specific class that starts the activity, but one needs to be set in the intent.

where is the best place to write the code to launch my activities ? is it in the same activity that starts the other activity? or have some outside logic about it?

I have an activity A

from which i need to start activity B

where do i put the logic of

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, requestingB);
```

Comment: Your question is vague at best.

Comment: When do you want to launch Activity B?

Comment: usually at the click of a button

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to have an activity that can be launched by some other application and you don't want the activity to necessarily know about what is launching it.

Try using an `intent-filter` within your activity. Then, when something needs to launch it, all it has to do is fire off an intent with the action defined in the `intent-filter`.

As always, Vogella has a good tutorial here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html

Comment: I have a navigation schema that i must follow, however somewhere down the line, this schema changes on a weekly basis, i dont want to start looking for all the places where i put "now launch login activity, now launch main activity, now launch this activity"

Comment: Ahh! In that case, I suggest looking into dependency injection. My preferred framework is RoboGuice!

Comment: I am using RoboGuice, but how do you solve the issue of navigation ? where a concrete class must be given as the parameter, can you show me an example ?

Answer (score 0):

As the OP mentioned in comments that he wants to start another activity on the click of a button, below is the sample code:

```
Button myBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but1);

myBut.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener()
{
    @override
    public void onClick(View view)
    { 
       Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
       startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: no, this is not what i am asking
I am not asking how to start an activity.
I am asking : how to "loosely couple" the class, that i need to load, upon starting the activity